# Docusaurus migrate error: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Tags: docusaurus

I am trying to migrate a Docusaurus v1 site to Docusaurus v2. When I run the migrate command, I get the following error and stack trace. Not sure what the problem is.

PS C:\docusaurus> npx @docusaurus/migrate migrate c:\docusaurus\old-site\OldSiteName\website c:\docusaurus\test-site

npx: installed 412 in 46.633s
Starting migration from v1 to v2...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined
at createConfigFile (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\lib\index.js:170:125)
at createMigrationContext (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\lib\index.js:80:26)
at migrateDocusaurusProject (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\lib\index.js:83:30)
at C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\bin\index.js:21:5
at Command. (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\bin\index.js:45:42)
at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\node_modules\commander\index.js:413:31)
at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\node_modules\commander\index.js:914:14)
at Command._dispatchSubcommand (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\node_modules\commander\index.js:865:18)
at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\node_modules\commander\index.js:882:12)
at Command.parse (C:\Users\sam.phillips\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\19476\node_modules@docusaurus\migrate\node_modules\commander\index.js:717:10)
PS C:\docusaurus>

Answer (score 1):

You have to add at least one `headerLink` in `siteConfig.js`:

```js
  // For no header links in the top nav bar -> headerLinks: [],
  //headerLinks: [],
  headerLinks: [
    { doc: 'docs', label: 'Documentation' },
  ],
```

Other option is to remove `headerLinks` completly.